# How to Using SignatureTypes.RSASHA1 in OAuthBase.cs

Tags: c#, google-oauth

I've searched many web sites and got the same result, just like the codes below...

```
public string GenerateSignature(Uri url, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string token, string tokenSecret, string httpMethod, string timeStamp, string nonce, SignatureTypes signatureType, string callback, string verifier,string body_hash, out string normalizedUrl, out string normalizedRequestParameters)
    {
        normalizedUrl = null;
        normalizedRequestParameters = null;

        switch (signatureType)
        {
            case SignatureTypes.PLAINTEXT:
                return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Format("{0}&{1}", consumerSecret, tokenSecret));
            case SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1:
                string signatureBase = GenerateSignatureBase(url, consumerKey, token, tokenSecret, httpMethod, timeStamp, nonce, HMACSHA1SignatureType, callback, verifier,body_hash, out normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters);

                HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1();
                hmacsha1.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}&{1}", UrlEncode(consumerSecret), string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenSecret) ? "" : UrlEncode(tokenSecret)));

                return GenerateSignatureUsingHash(signatureBase, hmacsha1);
            case SignatureTypes.RSASHA1:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown signature type", "signatureType");
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how to Implement "SignatureTypes.RSASHA1" in C# ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, But just since I ran into this recently, The solution looks a bit like this :

```
var rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(... Your key as XML ...) 

var sha = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signatureBaseString));

var hashBytes = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.SignHash(sha, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

var result = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
```